# Eclipse workspace projects suddenly have bad build path

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

I generated several Java projects last spring. Today I opened Eclipse back up and selected the workspace I used in the spring but now all the projects have a red X on them. They all list the same problem:

`**The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project.**`

The build path looks ok (I think). I tried to create a new project as an experiment to see it there are differences. The new project dialog box has `**Use default JRE (Currently jre7)**` checked and a warning at the bottom:

`**The current workspace uses a 1.4 JRE with compiler compliance level 1.7. This is not recommendes and either the JRE or the compiler level should be changed.**`

Not sure what changed since last spring but something obviously has. I don't really understand what it is trying to tell me. ?Anybody have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Update: I created a new project and compared its buildpath to one of the projects from last spring. In the new project, it has: `**JRE System Library [JRE7]**`
In the old project that now has the problem I see: `**JRE System Library [JAVASE-1.7](unbound)**`.

Somehow I think the "unbound" means something bad. Still do not understand how it was ok last spring and now suddenly it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "unbound" means that there is no JRE at the path specified in the classpath. My guess is that, since last spring, modifications were made to your java installation(s).

To bind your project back on a JRE, click on your "unbound" JRE and click on the "Edit..." button. In the Edit Library window, select a working JRE (JRE 7 would probably be a good choice in your case), then click on Finish. The "Unbound" message should disappear and your classpath should be okay afterwards.